# Android Studio Constraint Layout Preview is different than phone screen

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to program an activity in android studio that will be, at least, similar in any device. In order to achieve this, I'm already using:

- Constraint Layout;
- Text size as sp and other sizes as dp;
- Same resolution (1920x1080) in my android preview and my physical device.

But, I'm getting a different screen behavior in each screen, as you can see by the pics.

Major differences are:

- Text size seems different even using "sp" unit to define it;
- Phone have a line break but preview not;
- Preview has a much larger blank space when compared to the phone.

What is happening? How could I prevent this behavior and design similar layouts for different phone screens?

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="45dp">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:paddingRight="30dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/templatetv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="TextView1"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textview1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Name: John Sample"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textview2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Document number: XXX.XXX.XXX-XX"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textview3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Father name: John Sample"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textview4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Mother name: Eva Sample"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textview5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Birthdate: 01/01/1901"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[Android Studio Screen Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehwiF.jpg)
[Phone Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eouQF.jpg)

Comment: It is likely that your preview and your physical device have different _pixel densities_ for their screens. That is, even though they're both 1920x1080 `px`, they are probably very different resolutions in terms of `dp`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this part, I think that can be the margin:

```
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" >
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to define different layouts for different screens. Also, if you follow material design guidelines most of the problems will not arise. checkout the [google material design documentation](https://material.io/).